# Meaning of "params" in @RequestMapping annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I am aware of @RequestMapping annotation which is used in Spring MVC based application.

I came across this piece of code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, params = {"someParam"})
```

I understood the `method`. However I don't know what `params` means? Before this I never had seen anything which passed params to this annotation.

Can anyone help in understanding this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your example means that the parameter `someParam` must be present in the request. This is used to narrow down the matching methods for the given request.

See the documentation: [RequestMapping#params](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--)

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Is this technique still prevalent?

Comment: I can't really tell. If I design a new API, I don't use. Instead I use different URLs to distinguish different method. However, if you have to reimplement an existing API or split a too overloaded method into two, it might come in handy.

Comment: Thanks again for your response, need to do some more study on this.

Comment: It definitely makes sense in quite a few cases. The simplest example is fetch all vs fetch one. Fetch all could use `@GetMapping(params = "!id") public fetch() {...}` and fetch one could use `@GetMapping(params = "id") fetch(String id) {...}`. The other option would be a single method which supports both cases using an if-test which is less clean imo.